# Delete all files but not directory

Tags: cmd, delete-file

```
echo Process Run time: %DATE% %TIME% >> log1.txt 
echo  Disconnecting the Existing Drive if Any  >> log1.txt
net use E: /delete

net use E: \\myserver_ddl\mydrive$ /USER:user1\my_test Password
xcopy /s E:\*.* \\another_server_share_loc\tmp
rem del %pathtofolder%\*.*   /s /f  /q
```

1. After copying files to `\\another_server_share_loc\tmp` I want to delete all files from all folder but I do not want to delete any sub-directory `\\myserver_ddl\mydrive$` (it is a drive with many folders with subfolders)
2. I want redirect the output in another file along with the pathname from where I am copying the file

Comment: Add 4 blank spaces to the start of every code line in your question.  The editor has that feature also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To delete all files on the E: mapped drive after xcopy has finished, with a log, try this:

```
del e:\*.*? /s >>"%userprofile%\desktop\file.log"
```

Comment: one more help 
I wish you could provide solution to this
before doing any operation i use 
net use E: /delete

but everytime i run the script i get below, any way to avoid this.

There are open files and/or incomplete directory searches pending on the connect
ion to E:.
Is it OK to continue disconnecting and force them closed? (Y/N) [N]:

Comment: Try this - I haven't tested it: `echo y|net use E: /delete`